# Java Multiple comparision in java

Tags: java

Pardon me if this is a stupid question.. I was wondering if there is any support for following comparison in Java:

`(a, b, c .... != null)`  in place for :

```
(a != null && b != null && c != null && d ! null and so on ..)
```

I was trying to make code more readable as my code which is almost unreadable due to multiple condition in single statement.

code :

```
variable = (rest.host != null && rest.payload != null 
    && rest.lockQueue != null && rest.endpoint != null ) || rest.default.setState 
    || rest.scheduler.locked && rest.scheduler.queue.isFull() 
    && lastPayload.getActivity.status.executing ? onExecute(rest.payload) : wait(TIME);
```

Comment: create a method that would check all those for nulls and just use that method in your if statement instead

Comment: I'm going to honestly say I find your original code more readable than any of the alternatives in the answers.

Comment: I appreciate all answers of which most of them is learning for me but I am still trying to make this piece a very easy to read so that it can be easily followed by users. something like (&&(a,b,c))  || (&&(d,e,f)) || defaulCase

Comment: @AnkurSaran, in my opinion, sometimes you have to abstract some of your code to keep it readable. You could do it using tiny methods. When the user wants to know what this comparisson does, it will just look to its declaraction. I think the idea of "getting all packed in one line and keep it readable" its utopic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your elements are in a collection, use `collection.stream().allMatch(x -> x != null)`. Actually, there's even a predicate for that: `collection.stream().allMatch(Objects::nonNull)`.

If your elements aren't in a collection, you can still use `Arrays.asList()` to create an ad-hoc list from them. So, in your case:

```
Arrays.asList(rest.host, rest.payload, rest.lockQueue, rest.endpoint).stream().allMatch(Objects::nonNull)
```

EDIT: actually, as someone mentioned in another answer, there is a method that creates a stream directly, namely `Stream.of(...)`. So:

```
Stream.of(rest.host, rest.payload, rest.lockQueue, rest.endpoint).allMatch(Objects::nonNull)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this to make sure everything is not null, if using a Java version lower than 8. Otherwise I would go with the other people's answers using streams.

```
private boolean checkIfNotNull( Object ... objects ) {
    for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if(objects[i] == null)
             return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and you could pass in all the objects that you want to check if they are null.

then you can call this in the if statement such as

```
if( checkIfNotNull( a, b, c, d, e, f, g ) ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In java 8, it could be done as next `Stream.of(a, b, c, d).allMatch(Objects::nonNull)`, it will return `true` if they are all non `null`.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you want your code more readable, you should replace your comparisons with method calls that "says" what each comparison is.

Example:

```
if (isAllRight(a, b, c)) {
...
}
```

In other cases you can break them into single comparisons and check one by one:

```
if (a == NUL) {
    return false;
}

if (b == NULL) {
    return false;
}

return true;
```